# How to use path in react Router Route for the following format

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to use the following path in React Router

http://localhost:3000/testgroup/test/callback/?code=2d54b51d

I'm using the following code to declare the path but its not working. Any idea on how to use this? It works on callback/:code but my callback url comes in the above format from the source. Also, how do I extract the code from the url in react router. Please note, I'm using the older version as the current application is in the older version.

```
 <TestRoute
          
          // authenticated={true}
          path={`${userRoute}/test/callback/?code=:code`}
          component={CallBackHandler}
          history={history}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router-dom` only concerns itself with the *path* portion of a URL, the queryString isn't used for path matching.

1. Remove the queryString from the route path.

   ```
   <TestRoute
     // authenticated
     path={`${userRoute}/test/callback/`}
     component={CallBackHandler}
     history={history}
   />
   ```
2. Read the queryString params from the `location` object in the component once it is mounted. It's useful to create a custom hook to access the `location.search` and return a memoized `URLSearchParams` object.

   ```
   const { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

   const useSearchParams = () => {
     const { search } = useLocation();
     return React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
   };

   const CallBackHandler = props => {
     const searchParams = useSearchParams();
     const code = searchParams.get("code");

     ...
   };
   ```